# Conditional data structure (object) access

Tags: javascript

I have a set of JavaScript functions that handle certain objects. All these objects have the following flexibility:

- Fields can be accessed like this: `data[prop][sub-prop][etc.]`, OR
- Like this (with a **type** sub-structure): `data[TYPE][prop][sub-prop][etc.]`.

The object is accessed in many places, and the condition (let's call it `is_mixed`) is relevant everywhere.

I thought of the following alternatives:

1. Always access `data` like this: `(is_mixed ? data[TYPE] : data)[prop][sub-prop][etc.]`
2. Have a function called getData and always access `data` like this: `getData()[prop][sub-prop][etc.]`.
   The function code would be:

   `function getData() { return is_mixed ? data[TYPE] : data; }`
3. Run the following on every new input: `if (is_mixed) { data = data[TYPE]; }`

It seems to me that options 2 and 3 might be copying the object data (which might be big) and performance is important here (I didn't find the literature to support this guess), but option 1 will make the code big and ugly.

Is there a better option? What's the best way to acheive this in terms of performance, code quality and basically best practices?

Comment: And JavaScript objects are manipulated by *reference*. Passing objects into and out of functions does not result in object copies being constructed.

Comment: You're right it's an object (parsed JSON). If all access is by reference it's great, I can use option 2 or 3. Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that options 2 and 3 might be copying the JSON content

No, they won't. They both just copy an object reference, which is quick and cheap (like copying a boolean). #2 is of course **slightly** slower, since it's a function call, but if it's used a **lot**, any decent JavaScript engine will inline the function anyway, giving you the benefit of modularity at the source level. (It can take thousands of calls to the function in a shortish period of time to make that kick in, though; e.g., a modern engine only bothers with optimization when it looks likely to matter.)